# Galaxy Nexus Capture image without starting preview?

Tags: android, camera, preview

I don't have a Galaxy Nexus and it's impossible to buy one. Therefore I would like to know if anyone knows the answer to this question specifically targeted to Galaxy Nexus.

```
SurfaceView sf = new SurfaceView(this);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(sf.getHolder);
camera.startPreview()
```

Using this code I am able to take a picture without showing the camera preview. However, this code doesn't work on Galaxy Nexus. Even if I changed `SurfaceView` to `SurfaceTexture`.

Any idea how I can do it on a Galaxy Nexus?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a dummy SurfaceView for this device. In documentation its specified that a SurfaceView (valid surface view) should be provided before start Preview, I also did try and it run over almost all devices except Galaxy Nexus